# Error: "No Bugsnag API Key set" while creating release build with proguard enabled in react native android

Tags: android, react-native, bugsnag

The logcat trace of the same:

2022-08-02 14:55:41.358 26505-26652/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL
EXCEPTION: mqt_native_modules

Process: com.ProjectName, PID: 26505

com.facebook.react.common.JavascriptException: Error: No Bugsnag API Key set, stack:

value@1407:2064
s@1407:697
_@1377:806
p@1377:694
start@1377:1767
@1376:130
h@2:1585
@2009:142
h@2:1585
@1983:160
h@2:1585
@403:696
h@2:1585
@6:53
h@2:1585
d@2:958
global code@2099:3

Answer (score 1):

This issue is resolved now.

I need to comment below line from gradle.properties

**android.enableR8.fullMode=true**